# Ubuntu skip lock-screen, go straight to login?

Tags: boot, grub2, login, laptop, 17.04

kicking and screaming I am trying to force myself to migrate to 17.04. I am using it screen-less and keep forgetting that I need to hit "Enter" at the first screen that shows the one and only user name, before I can get to enter the login pass-phrase.

Is there some way I can have it go straight to the login-name screen, just as 14.04 and 16.04 do. There will only ever be one user on this system.

In case you are wondering, why screen-less: It's a laptop attached to a full size monitor and that monitor gets nothing to display until after I have logged in. The login is all in the dark on the disable laptop screen.

Pretty useless actually, I thought by now I could get the grub and login information on the attached monitor. I have tried everything I can find to get that on the big monitor at boot, but nothing works -- yet.

Thanks

Comment: Would it be OK to skip login and arrive directly at the logged in desktop?

Comment: @sudodus, thanks for the reply, but no, I still want the security of logging in, just not having to select one of one user. :)